# How to make small footer with percentage sized images?

Tags: html, css, footer

I created a footer that displays the social media symbols as small 40px x 40px images. However, in order to ensure that the footer looks alike across all screen sizes, I want to change the pixel height and width to % height and width. I tried setting `<img>` and `<a>` to `width:100%` and `height:100%`, but that just creates a really larger footer. How do I make a small footer with percentage sized images (preferably, the percentage sized images are the same size as 40px x 40px images)?

**HTML:**

```
 <footer>
    <div class = "footerTitle"> Check out Downtown Ithaca: </div>
    <ul> 
        <li> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/downtownithaca" target="_blank"><img class="footerImage" src="images/facebook.png" alt="facebook" width = "40"></a> </li>
        <li> <a href="https://twitter.com/downtownithaca" target="_blank"> <img class="footerImage" src="images/twitter5.png" alt = "twitter" width="40"></a></li>
        <li> <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/downtownithaca" target="_blank"> <img class="footerImage" src="images/youtube.png" alt = "youtube" width="40"></a></li> 
    </ul>
  </footer>
```

**CSS:**

```
footer {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center; /*ensures text inside footer & ul is centered*/
}

.footerTitle {
  padding: 0.5% 0 0.1% 0; 
}

.footerImage {
  height: 40px;
}

footer ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0.5% 0;

}

footer li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.784% 2%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set your footer with small fixed height then it is not good to set images in percentage of height and width because it will not set the image with full display into footer. Either you can set center of background-image for the container and set into `anchor` tag.

I have changed some html element here, also check in this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c581vvd0/)

**Note:** I have set footer with fixed position for display purpose only you can set it as per your requirement.

```
<div class="footer">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/downtownithaca" target="_blank"><div class="icon facebook"></div></a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/downtownithaca" target="_blank"><div class="icon twitter"></div></a>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/downtownithaca" target="_blank"><div class="icon youtube"></div></a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<style>
    body{
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #c1c1c1;
    }
    .footer{
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 30px;
        background-color: #000;
    }
    a{
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .footer .icon{
        width: 33%;
        height: 30px;
        float: left;
        background-size: 20px 20px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
    }
    .clear{
        clear: both;
    }
    .facebook{
        background-image: url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-flat-rounded-rects/512/facebook-256.png");
    }
    .twitter{
        background-image: url("https://media.paper-republic.org/img/twitter.png");
    }
    .youtube{
        background-image: url("http://www.mofang.com.tw/statics/v4/tw_tyong/img/youtube_icon.jpg");
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give footer as table display and make children table-cell. so each element will be center aligned. image inline-block so that it can height and width property. hope it helps.

```
<style>
footer {
display : table;
width: 100%;
height : 60px;
}
footer > div {
display : table-cell;
vertical-align :middle;
}
footer > div image {
display : inline-block;
width : 50%;
}
</style>
<footer>
<div> text goes here </div>
<div> Image goes here </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score -2):

You should give your footer the dynamic height instead of giving the child element size.

Comment: What a crap answer.

Comment: Im new to Stackoverflow. Formatting problem eradicated a word so it looked messy. But still I tried to answer. Be grateful atleast

Comment: How do you give a footer a dynamic height?